# How to show the images with the same magnification in Octave

Tags: octave, imshow

I'd like to show two images with the same magnification in Octave. But the imshow function in Octave doesn't support the property of "initialMagnification" while Matlab supports this property.

How can I do in Octave?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Is "magnification" is the same as zoom? If yes just compute xlim and ylim and set them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the axis to the desired "zoomed" ranges. The command is axis, and is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Axis-Configuration.html#XREFaxis).

```
figure(1);
A = randn (10000, 1);
plot(A);

figure(2);
plot(A);
axis([30,50])
```